# Does the Tomcat PersistentManager allow non-sticky session replication?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8, tomcat9

And in case it does, does a tomcat instance always query the persistent store to fetch session information?
I cannot find a good/any source on this. Even the official documentation is sparse on details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two separate concerns here - persistence and non-sticky sessions.

The Tomcat PersistentManager persists in-memory sessions so that they live beyond a Tomcat restart. The PersistentManager is not engaged in non-sticky sessions.

To support non-sticky sessions requires so-called session replication across the Tomcat nodes - also called a [Tomcat cluster](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/cluster-howto.html). Session replication is achieved by broadcasting in-memory changes (including creation) to a session on a node to all other nodes.

Comment: Yes, I get that. I have gone through the documentation on clustering. I would have to use either the DeltaManager or the BackupManager. However, they don't have the feature of persistence. Will it be possible to use for example, the PersistentManager with the BackupManager?

Comment: This is a new question

Comment: Please consider answering this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76386778/how-to-use-the-tomcat-persistentmanager-with-the-backupmanager