# How to use the Tomcat PersistentManager with the BackupManager?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8, tomcat9

I would like to use the PersistentManager for persistence and the BackupManager for session clustering/replication to create non-sticky sessions.

Comment: No, this is not possible. Only one session manager can be configured per web application. Received a direct reply from a Tomcat maintainer on their mailing list https://markmail.org/message/mbgnkp223b2zmuu5

Answer (score 0):

I would do the cluster management with `DeltaManager`, rather than `BackupManager`. It's more widely used and more mature.

As long as at least one node is running it is not necessary to persist the session because it is preserved by the remaining node, which can change as nodes are spun-up and brought-down. Therefore you do not need `PersistentManager`.

Comment: Yes, it may not be strictly required. However, I was asking about the possibility of doing so. For example - when using the DeltaManager, since each node has a copy of the session information, if I was able to periodically persist from just one node using the PersistentManager.